# Class is not mapped exception in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have hibernate configuration file as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://10.162.9.130:5432/mining</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Mapping files are written and included in mams-hibern.xml file as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource" /></property>
<property name="mappingResources">
<list>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantAddressHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantContactHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantLeases.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/GeneratedChallan.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OffenderType.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OffenceDetailRule.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/TemperoryAppNotes.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/TemperoryFilePath.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OtherDocuments.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OffenceSubactsRules.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OffenceActRules.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Vehicles.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApprovedMajorMineral.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/GoogleImage.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/PasswordHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/LeaseTransfer.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/TransferApplicantCompany.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/MailSettings.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/LeaseCompanyAddress.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/FinancialYear.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/IncomeTax.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AdditionalCharge.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/MenuPrivileges.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AddressType.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AdvaloramRoyalty.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Agent.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AppJawsize.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Applicant.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantAddress.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantCompany.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantContact.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantLogin.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantStatus.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Application.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationDocument.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationMineral.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationSpecificQuery.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationSpecificQueryValues.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationStatus.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationSurvey.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationType.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplnSecurityFee.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AreaSpecification.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Bank.hbm.xml</value>
</property>
</beans>
```

The following code is executed  successfully,

```
Applicant applicant=null;
Object[] ob={leaseNo,Integer.parseInt(appType)};
Session session=getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
if(session!=null){
    Query query=session.createQuery("select a from Applicant as a inner join a.applications as b inner join " +
    "b.applicationType as c inner join b.permits as d where d.permitNo=? and c.applicationTypeId=?");
    query.setParameters(ob,  new Type []{Hibernate.STRING,Hibernate.INTEGER});
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Applicant> apllApplicants=query.list();

}
tx.commit();
```

My problem is when executing the following code,an exception is occurred

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
Session session =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();              
Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
Query query=session.createQuery("select a from Applicant as a inner join a.applications as b inner join " +
        "b.applicationType as c inner join b.permits as d where d.permitNo=? and c.applicationTypeId=?");
query.setParameters(ob,  new Type []{Hibernate.STRING,Hibernate.INTEGER});
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Applicant> apllApplicants=query.list();
tx.commit();
```

The exception is

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Applicant is not mapped d [select a from Applicant as a inner join a.applications as b inner join b.applicationType as c inner join b.permits as d where d.permitNo=? and c.applicationTypeId=?]
```

What is the solution for this.Any one know please help me

Answer (score 1):

You are working in two different context:

1. **first example - Spring-context**: Session is built via `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, responsible of loading `hibernate.cfg.xml` AND all mappings as described in `spring-context.xml`
2. **second example - Native Hibernate**: Session is built using Hibernate's `Configuration` responsible of loading ONLY `hibernate.cfg.xml` which doesn't contains class mappings; add `<mapping resource="path.to.your.mappedClass.hbm.xml"/>` to your `hibernate.cfg.xml` to solve the problem.

Comment: My question is that,how we can reuse mapping files declared in Spring-context in  hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: you have to use an Hibernate Mapping file as described at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm